# How to get data from mobile apps?

Tags: android, mobile

I am working on a project that collects shop information, including address, business hour and phone number of a company.

The data is in the mobile apps.

How to retrieve data from a mobile apps?

Some people suggest adb command, how does it work?

Is there any software which can let user control the mobile apps, just like selenium controlling the browser and get data?

Any other methods?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you should use webservice from website and get Data 
User Prouduct and...
you just study these link

https://www.restapitutorial.com/

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/what_are_web_services.htm

Comment: Thank you, Amin. I will take a look on the websites.